# Visual Studio Code: "ImportError: No module named 'environ'" but django-environ installed

Tags: django, python-3.x, visual-studio-code, importerror

I have this problem repently.
When execute the debugger I get this error: ImportError: No module named 'environ'
But actually I have installed this module with pip.
The version of VSC is 1.38.1
Django 2.2
django-environ installed is 0.4.5

debug config:

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python: Django",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/manage.py",
            "args": [
                "runserver",
                "--noreload"
            ],
            "django": true,
            "pythonPath": "${workspaceFolder}/env3/bin/python3"
        }
    ]
}
```

Any help? Ideas?
Thank you!

Comment: Are you sure that you installed `django-environ` inside your virtual environment?

Comment: Pip freeze output:
`astroid==2.2.5
dj-database-url==0.5.0
Django==2.2.5
**django-environ==0.4.5**
django-extra-views==0.12.0
django-heroku==0.3.1
gunicorn==19.9.0
isort==4.3.21
lazy-object-proxy==1.4.2
mccabe==0.6.1
pkg-resources==0.0.0
psycopg2==2.8.3
psycopg2-binary==2.8.3
pylint==2.3.1
pytz==2019.2
six==1.12.0
sqlparse==0.3.0
typed-ast==1.4.0
whitenoise==4.1.3
wrapt==1.11.2` But the package is not found in env/lib/python3.5/site-packages...

Comment: How about your `settings.json` file on your workspace? you should see something like this on `.vscode/settings.json`: `"python.pythonPath": "/Users/username/to/your/env/folder/bin/python",`. If you didn't see it, you could press `Cmd + Shift + P`, type Interpreter then you'll see `Python: Select Interpreter` then click it. It will show a list of envs on your computer then you just need to choose the right one which you have installed django-environ

Comment: Hi! thankyou for your answer but the problem persists :( perhaps django-environ is installed glabally but what problem with that?

Comment: There is no problem with that, I just think that because the Python interpreter you're using on VSCode is different than the one you've used to install django-environ. That's why it caused the error

Comment: Ok, the problem was resolved. Is some rare but when I copied and pasted the working directory with similar name VisualStudioCode execute the old project venv path. I delete the old project and change the name of root to first project name. Thankyou Toan Quoc Ho for your help.

Comment: Glad to hear that you solved your problem